# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.setHandleCustomPasswordTypes(Z)VI am

Tags: web-services, security, rampart

I am getting following error. I am using WSS4j1.5.8 i.e. Rampart 1.5 and AXIS2-1.4:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.ws.security.WSSConfig.setHandleCustomPasswordTypes(Z)V

When I used Rampart 1.4 i.e. wss4j 1.5.7 and AXIS2 1.4 it gives me following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.ws.security.WSSecurityEngineResult.get(Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;

Here at least call goes to PasswordCallbackHandler class but gives above error.

Answer (score 0):

You've probably used a incompatible version of wss4j and rampart. If you run the code in a application server it can be a classloader problem - the server contains a different version of wss4j with the higher priority in the chains of classloaders.